# How do I insert records using Entity Framework with nested list of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am making a call to an endpoint and receiving back a list of objects, let's call them `Receipts`. Each Receipt can contain a list of a variable amount of `Vehicles`. I want to be saving records with a composite key comprised of the Receipt ID and Vehicle ID.

I set up the model as:

```
public class Receipt
{
        [Key]
        [Column(Order=1)]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public List<Vehicles> vehicles { get; set; }

        public class Vehicles
        {
            [Key]
            [Column(Order=2)]
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
 }
```

Next, I added Receipt to the DbContext

```
public class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Receipt> Receipt { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, I insert/update and save changes

```
try
{
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
    {
         dbContext.Receipt.AddOrUpdate(receipt);
         dbContext.Receipt.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My program is not catching any exceptions but the table/database is completely empty. Am I structuring the object right to inform Entity Framework of how I want these rows saved? One option would be to loop through each Vehicle in a Receipt and create a new Entity that stores the Receipt ID and Vehicle ID along with other fields needed

Comment: You will need to make your `Vehicles` property in the `Receipt` class as `public virtual ICollection<Vehicles> Vehicles {get; set;}`. Additionally, I would recommend taking out the nested class `Vehicles` into its own separate class. That will allow EF to properly work out the details of the changes and update DB.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Separating Vehicles into a separate class, marking the Vehicle ID as `[Key][Column(Order=2)]`, and then setting the property in Receipt to `public virtual ICollection<>` only adds a Vehicle table to EF (which I don't want) and is still empty. Wanting a record of rows that contain each Vehicle and the Order it is associated with

Answer (score 0):

As your database is completely empty and your code does not show any sign of it either, I'm afraid the solution to your question is to actually *call*

```
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

To make it really work as expected, as mentioned in a comment, your property should be a

```
public virtual ICollection<Vehicles> Vehicles { get; set; }
```

and although I don't know if it's a problem, I would recommend putting your Vehicle class as a normal non-nested class.

Comment: I am calling `SaveChanges()`, editing my post to include that sorry. I had seen the nested classes in a past example and have done that previously and it worked fine, but will start moving those out into their own class. This did not fix the issue, as table is still empty and it created an unneeded Vehicle table

Comment: Made a simple mistake and fixed it. Everything is set-up exactly as you mentioned, but I get an `EntityValidationError` now when trying to save